# How does this for loop is work?

Tags: python

Please let me know how this for loop is working.

```
b= [4,5,6]
for b[-1] in b:
   print(b[-1])
```

This code snippet is giving me output as:-

```
4
5
5
```

I checked it with Python 2.7

Comment: You can run your code at pythontutor.com to get really good visualization.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Using tricky expressions like `b[-1]` in a for loop header is not typical production-quality style, so I'm guessing this was originally intended as a "guess this code's behavior" kind of riddle. Maybe sharing its source with us will provide additional useful context.

Comment: yeah, it was a riddle question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can understand it while printing the whole `b` list:

```
b= [4,5,6]
for b[-1] in b:
    print(b)
    print(b[-1])
```

Output

```
[4, 5, 4]  # first iteration, you set last element(6) with first element(4) [4,5,6] -> [4,5,4]
4
[4, 5, 5]  # second iteration, you set last element(4) with element(5), [4,5,4] -> [4,5,5]
5
[4, 5, 5]  # last iteration, you set last element(5) with element(5), no change
5
```

So basically every iteration your last element becomes the element you iterate with.

Answer (score 6):

Each iteration, element i of b is picked. It is attributed to b[-1] (last element of b) and printed. So each step, the last element of b (6 before the loop) is attributed the value of the ith element.

Eventually, at the last iteration, the ith value is read and the value read is the value that was written the iteration before (that is, 5).

Modify the code to print b at each step and it becomes obvious:

```
b = [4,5,6]
for b[-1] in b:
    print(b[-1])
    print(b)
```

(Don't do this kind of things in real life.)

Comment: So why does `5` get printed in the last iteration and not 6?